# RNBlurModalView for displaying UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

i'm recently find this awesome modal view popover ([source](https://github.com/rnystrom/RNBlurModalView)).

"Usage" section there is telling how to show `RNBlurModalView` with UIView in it with following code:

```
    RNBlurModalView *modal = [[RNBlurModalView alloc] initWithViewController:self view:view];
    [modal show];
```

Everything works fine when i'm using `RNBlurModalView` to show custom UIView like square with following code:

```
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 200)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 5.f;
    view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    view.layer.borderWidth = 5.f;

    RNBlurModalView *modal = [[RNBlurModalView alloc] initWithViewController:self view:view];
    [modal show];
```

, but i'm having problem when i'm trying to show `UIView` from `UIViewController` in `RNBlurModalView`, it just shows empty modal view, here's code that i'm using:

```
    ExampleViewContoller *exampleVC = [[ExampleViewContoller alloc]init];
    RNBlurModalView *modal = [[RNBlurModalView alloc] initWithViewController:self view:exampleVC.view];
    [modal show];
```

Here is image of ExampleViewController from storyboard if needed - [image]

---

**Question** : any ideas what am i doing wrong, why modal view is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem is with which you are calling for viewcontrollers view .
Try this

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
ExampleViewContoller *exampleVC = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ExampleViewContoller"];;
RNBlurModalView *modal = [[RNBlurModalView alloc] initWithViewController:self view:exampleVC.view];
[modal show];
```

Note dont forget to set the storyboardId of the  ExampleViewContoller as "ExampleViewContoller"in the storyboard.